# (Excel) How to copy only duplicate values from one column to another spreadsheet and automate it?

Tags: excel, duplicates, copy

I am trying to copy only duplicate values from one column to another Excel spreadsheet and automate it. I am looking for a function, so that the process can be faster than manual changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With `Excel-365` try-

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A100,COUNTIFS(A2:A100,A2:A100)>1))
```

[image]

Comment: oh that's amazing, took my laptop good 10 minutes to count it, because of the 12000 cells, but worked like a charm! Than you so much for the help!

Comment: although it has one issue. When the value starts with "0" and ends with number X, the formula neglects the 0s. Example: values "01" and "0001" are considered the same. Is there a way to fix that?